# How to make a piston turn a block into an item on Minecraft for PS4?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm trying to make an auto cobblestone farm and have been trying to make a piston push a block into another slab to drop it into a hopper as an item and into a chest.

However I don't believe it is working because I am playing on ps4 edition. Is there another way to make it happen for PS4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make an automatic cobblestone breaker?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/217457/how-can-i-make-an-automatic-cobblestone-breaker)

Comment: @Hacker Not a duplicate because this is Legacy Console edition and that is Java Edition.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to break cobble automatically using only redstone and pistons. You can, however, use TNT, creepers, and withers to destroy the blocks.

Comment: This post is a possible duplicate of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/217457/how-can-i-make-an-automatic-cobblestone-breaker

Answer (score 0):

If you're playing on 1.14, I do believe that TNT duplicators aren't patched yet. So you can use it to break the blocks as TNT now drops all blocks it breaks. Place a collection at the bottom and coat it in obsidian. If you don't know how to make a TNT duplicator, I think YouTuber Mumbo Jumbo has a tutorial on how to do it. If not you should be able to find one by someone else.